# Stormpath, how to detect if user signed in with Google account?

Tags: express, stormpath

It was super easy to integrate Google login for  this fine tutorial:

https://stormpath.com/blog/build-nodejs-express-stormpath-app

I have to change the profile.jade file, so that `givenName` and `surname` are not displayed, if user has logged in with Google account.

The way it is now, if the user tries to change the 2 fields, the form response with error

*Oops! We encountered an unexpected error. Please contact support and explain what you were doing at the time this error occurred.*

This is to be expected, as those fields must be changed in Google account.

I'm able to access for any account via JSON:

```
"directory":{"href":"https://api.stormpath.com/v1/directories/49bXXXG8mAtthBTyE8ymdV"},
```

in my server.js file

```
req.user.directory
```

and I can look that up in Stormpath Admin panel, and it is indeed the Google directory. Then I can not display the 2 fields if a user belongs to that directory.

**Is there a better way?**
- like getting the **name** of the directory rather than the path?

Any suggestions are appreciate.

Comment: If you know the directory ID, you can make a GET request to "https://api.stormpath.com/v1/directories/$DIR_ID/provider". In the object that's returned, you'll be able to see the providerId.